# DRF sessions (AnonymusUser)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Не пойму почему пользователь теряется после логина по урлу login/. Если после логина перейти по урлу profile/, то выбивает ошибку о том, что пользователь анонимный, AnonymousUser.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileView, LoginView


urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False 
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'userprofile.apps.UserprofileConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

serializer.py:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    user_image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username', 'user_header', 'user_image']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.user.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.user.username)
        instance.user_header = validated_data.get('user_header', instance.user_header)

        user_image_data = validated_data.get('user_image')
        if user_image_data:
            format, imgstr = user_image_data.split(';base64,')
            ext = format.split('/')[-1]
            id = uuid.uuid4()
            data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name=id.urn[9:]+'.'+ext)
            instance.user_image.save(f'{id}.{ext}', data, save=False)

        instance.user.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            username = serializer.validated_data.get('username')
            password = serializer.validated_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print(request.session.session_key)
                return Response({'detail': 'Успешный вход в систему'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'error': 'Неверное имя пользователя или пароль'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
 

class ProfileView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request):
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'detail': 'Успешный вход в систему'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'error': 'Неверное имя пользователя или пароль'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'images/userphoto/', blank=True, null=True)
    user_header = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofile.save()
```